# Build, install and run yoink in python 2.7

Tags: python

I found this really cool project called "yoink", which is particularly useful when extraction of published 2D data is necessary:

https://github.com/mrterry/yoink

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywHqIEv3xXg&feature=youtu.be&t=1938

Unfortunately this project is no longer maintained and I am trying to figure out how to install this under python 2.7. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: good point. I did `pip install yoink` and the package was found. I got the following error though:`$ pip install yoink
Collecting yoink
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/c9/f0d48c07afc632240e836506e40143fbd87a38ed8b01b8d0f113a637875c/yoink-0.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-r8eq0_ea/yoink/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
        import distribute_setup
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distribute_setup'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ python setup.py install
```

does the trick! :)

Comment: It even installed under Python 3.7